# Avoid pentadactyl to reset theme when restarting firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Is there a way to "save" he options used with the firefox plug-in pentadactyl?

Indeed, for example, when I close firefox and re-open it, the "colorscheme" is reset to default. It happens either on Windows or on Linux.

I do not find information about this problem on the tutorials or pentadactyl theme related questions.

Thanks.

Comment: As written, this does not appear to be a programming specific question.  As such: Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic** for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Comment: Assuming I found the correct add-on (next time, please put a link in your question): [Pentadactyl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pentadactyl/?src=cb-dl-toprated) has both a [support site](http://groups.google.com/group/pentadactyl) and a support email link on its AMO page (both on right side of the page).  If you have not already tried these links, they should be your first point of contact. Given they are focused on your area of issue, you will probably be more successful at getting help there.

Answer (score 1):

After researches and tutorial, the answer is the following:

To take into account modification and modify the config file, it is necessary to perform a ":mkpentadactylrc"

The solution has been answered here: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pentadactyl/74IZm-O9kGo

You can read more about the different options of the plugin at this link: 
http://5digits.org/help/pentadactyl/starting.xhtml

The answer was in the C content: Saving settings .

Comment: Great to know you found by yourself. Could you add reference or method you used? Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .

Comment: Done, thank you for your feedback and sorry for the lack of accuracy. I just start on this website and want to help people that may have the same kind of troubles.